# Video streaming. Any way of setting bitrate depending on bandwidth?

Tags: video-streaming

Simply, I have a streaming client that streams to a local server and I grab data from it and push it to my own server with my own software.

I do it that way because the bandwidth is really variable (from 0.5mb to 5mb, changing constantly) and the streaming client warns about that, stopping the transmission, so my software grabs the data and retransmits it without warning about that and just resending packets not ACKed.

The thing now is, is there any protocol, library, something that I can use to change video kbps just in case it does not receive enough ACKs from the server, or that I can change it programmatically via API or something?

Fast question: As I can grab the video data as I want and encode it as I want, is there any way of changing video encoding on-the-fly with any software? I looked for ffmpeg but I can't do that from the command line.

Comment: ffmpeg has no way to be a "smart" server like this [though libx264 may even support it], however you can output to multiple bitrates [ex: HLS] and let the client switch, though I've never tried it.

Comment: Yes, I already knew about HLS. The problem is the upload bandwith, not the download one. I finally managed to modify ffmpeg when using libx264 to change bitrate on the fly and works like a charm.

Comment: that's awesome, care to post your patch somewhere so the rest of us can admire/use it? :)

Comment: Sure. Is only a few lines of code (a bit rubbish but perfect for my project). Let me finish my project and I publish it. In short, it simply creates a nonblocking UDP socket and each time it tries to encode a frame, first reads from the socket. If it manages to read a uint32, sets the new int as bitrate. My streaming software emits a local UDP packet each time it wants ffmpeg to change bitrate. And because x264 don't has constant bitrate per se and each frame can have a different size, changing his encoding params affects the next frames being encoded instantly without any problem.

Comment: Don't know how it works with other encoders.

Comment: @JorgeFuentesGonzález It's been a while since you worked on this but I have a really similar use-case for a personal project. I'd love to see how you implemented your solution. Would you mind sharing? :)

Comment: @Erwan Sure! I tried to talk with the ffmpeg dev team about this, but said that "not every user would need this feature", like every user uses the 100% of features that ffmpeg has. And still in 2023 they still don't have this feature although at least 10 persons have asked me about it, even via Facebook, sigh... Here is the thread with a quick dirty ffmpeg patch to show the proof of concept: https://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-devel/2016-August/197518.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

libx264 allows you to change the bitrate on the fly.

Comment: Adding this old ffmpeg proof of concept here: https://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-devel/2016-August/197518.html